# Slice can access another slice out of range but indexing out of range causes panic

Tags: go, slice, indexoutofboundsexception, semantics

My code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a := [10]int{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
    b := a[1:4]
    fmt.Println("a:", a)
    fmt.Println("b:", b)
    
    // Works fine even though c is indexing past the end of b.
    c := b[4:7]
    fmt.Println("c:", c)
    
    // This fails with panic: runtime error: index out of range [4] with length 3
    // d := b[4]
}
```

Output:

```
a: [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
b: [1 2 3]
c: [5 6 7]
```

If I uncomment the line that contains `d := b[4]`, it leads to this this error:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range [4] with length 3
```

My question:

Why is it okay to access `b[4:7]` even though the index 4 is out of range for `b` which has a length 3 but it is not okay to access `b[4]`? What Go language rules explain this behavior?

Comment: Why the downvotes? What can I do to make this question better?

Comment: Why is there a close vote with the reason as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo"? Which part of my question is not reproducible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Relevant rules: [Spec: Index expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) and [Spec: Slice expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions).

In short: when indexing, index must be less than the **length**. When slicing, upper index must be less than or equal to the **capacity**.

When indexing: `a[x]`

> the index `x` is *in range* if `0 <= x < len(a)`, otherwise it is *out of range*

When slicing: `a[low: high]`

> For arrays or strings, the indices are *in range* if `0 <= low <= high <= len(a)`, otherwise they are *out of range*. **For slices, the upper index bound is the slice capacity `cap(a)` rather than the length.**

When you do this:

```
b := a[1:4]
```

`b` will be a slice sharing the backing array with `a`, `b`'s length will be `3` and its capacity will be `9`. So later it is perfectly valid to slice `b` even beyond its length, up to its capacity which is `9`. But when indexing, you can always index only the part covered by the slice's length.

We use indexing to access current elements of a slice or array, and we use slicing if we want to create a fragment of an array or slice, or if we want to *extend* it. Extending it means we want a bigger portion (but what is still covered by the backing array).

Comment: @lone-learner, obligatory reading: [this](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro) then [this](https://blog.golang.org/slices), and you'll be 100% covered on slices.

Comment: icza, kostix: Thank you for the links to the spec and the Go Blog. I am still learning Go from [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/). I will read your links too after I successfully complete the tour.